# Applying a dependent type to an arguement to assert a goal in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

If I have a general setup like the following, how can I prove I assert (f a)?

```
A : Type
f : A -> Prop
a : A
...
============================
f a
```

Specifically, why can't I use any of these tactics, and what do the errors mean?

```
specialize (f a).
Error: Cannot change f, it is used in conclusion.

apply (f a).
Unable to unify "Prop" with "f a".
```

Comment: The context and goal as given are unsolvable. `f a` is the *statement* to be proven. It's not a *proof* of itself! E.g. the sentence "Today, it rained bananas." is a grammatically correct sentence, but it's not actually correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specialise `f` because it is used in the conclusion, that is in the goal.
`specalize (f a)` replaces your hypothesis `f` by its applied version.
If we forget about the goal that would get you `f : Prop` afterwards.
However since `f` appears in the goal you are not allowed to change its meaning.

Also `f a` is a proposition, and certainly not a proof of `f a` itself!
The fact that it is named `f` doesn't mean it's not a predicate.